# How to bypass XMLHttpRequest header protection for a CSRF attack

Tags: web-application, csrf

A client is only submitting forms using XMLHttpRequest with the use of a header (`X-Header: [any value would be correct]`) to protect against Cross Site Request Forgery attacks.

I know this is not the right way to prevent CSRF vulnerabilities, but how would you exploit this type of CSRF vulnerability?

The requirement is to send an HTTP request with a custom header.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Normal POST request can't be used to modify headers. Writing a similar XHR request won't work because same-origin policy, as making XHR requset on exampl1e.com to exmaple2.com can't be done on modern browsers.

Comment: It can when complying to CORS.

Comment: Need any further info adding to my answer?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very similar method to using the [`X-Requested-With` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533680/413180), just that `X-Header` is used instead (neither of which are standard headers, although [`X-Requested-With` could be considered a de-facto standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245601/413180)).

This is a valid method of preventing CSRF as only the following headers are allowed cross domain:

> - Accept
> - Accept-Language
> - Content-Language
> - Last-Event-ID
> - Content-Type

any others cause a "pre-flight" request to be issued in CORS supported browsers. Non CORS browsers will ignore other headers.

As long as the CORS configuration isn't allowing the header and domain the attacker is using then this is a valid method.

If CORS was enabled and was allowing the attacker's domain, then other methods of CSRF protection such as the recommended [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) would also fail because the attacker could make a GET request to retreive the token value (assuming the `access-control-allow-credentials` header is set to true). Note that [lack of CORS does not prevent requests from being made by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26526630/413180), it only prevents the responses from being read.

So, it appears that you're out of luck for a CSRF exploit, unless [another Flash or browser plugin bug/feature](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20060725/forging-http-request-headers-with-flash/) will allow you to add the header to the request.